# When does thenCompose make sense for CompletableFuture in Java

Tags: java, completable-future

I am new to Java async programming and trying to understand when it makes sense to use thenCompose() method.

Consider the following pseudo code:

```
CompletableFuture<T> firstStep = CompletableFuture.runAsync(firstBlah)
CompletableFuture<T> secondStep = firstStep.thenCompose( secondBlah )
```

As I understand, the second statement will cause firstBlah to be put as a runnable in the thread pool. Once the task completes, another runnable will be created and put into the thread pool.

I don't understand how thenCompose adds more efficiency. If the execution is going to be sequential anyway, why don't I incorporate secondBlah into firstBlah function itself? This way, only one runnable will be needed. The overhead of creating another runnable and passing the parameter from the first runnable into the second one can be eliminated.

Obviously, I am missing something. Thanks.

Comment: But you don't always control the declaration of `firstStep`. It could come from a third-party library. Maybe you get a `CompletableFuture` that returns the contents of a web page, and you want to do something with those contents.

Comment: It’s not always about efficiency, often times it is about code maintenance and composability. Technically, you can put all of your code in one single file and not worry about packages, modules or repositories. But have you ever tried working with or debugging a 50,000 line Java class?

Comment: The second statement will **not** cause “firstBlah to be put as a runnable in the thread pool”. The execution of the “firstBlah” runnable is already arranged by the first statement. The second statement does not change anything regarding `firstStep`.

Answer (score 0):

@SilvioMayolo and @AbhijitSarkar put some excellent points. Let me briefly summarize, and add some more.

Now, you are correct - there is no point in using `CompletableFuture::thenCompose` if you are already constructing the original `CompletableFuture`. But like @SilvioMayolo said, this method allows you to add "the last-minute touches" to a `CompletableFuture` before sending it out the door. If you don't have the ability to modify the original `CompletableFuture`, then this is a great way to ***compose*** certain functionalities on top of each other.

Here is the latest documentation for that method -- [`CompletableFuture::thenCompose`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenCompose(java.util.function.Function)). I bring this up because your `secondBlah` is actually a `Function<? super T, ? extends CompletionState<U>>`. That is to say, it is a `Function` that takes in the output of your first `CompletableFuture<T>` (`T output = myCompletableFuture.get();`), then uses that returned `output` to construct a new `CompletableFuture<U>`.

So in short, it's nothing more than a convenience function for when you want subsequent steps to be bundled in the same `CompletableFuture`, but without modifying the original. Good examples of similar contexts would be `Stream::flatMap` and `Optional::flatMap`. This function is essential `flatMap`, but for `CompletableFuture`. This really helps for keeping things modular, but connected where needed, which feeds into what @AbhijitSarkar was saying.